# Merging data in an axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I haven't done much graph stuff on excel.  Now, I have a job that will require graphs from time to time.  I figured out how to make the graph.  Now, I want to combine data from one axis.
I have multiple headers that are the same name and want to merge that data (if possible??)
So, all cold smoke together, all hot smoke together, etc.
How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: What does your data look like? Maybe reordering it will do the job?

Comment: Multiple people fill out a form for what our different product (smoked fish) tastes like. There are 6 categories that are rated on each form.  That form is put in a base on airtable.  I have to take the results from airtable and create a graph so we can see how the products are doing each month.

Comment: You really need to explain more clearly what you mean by "combine data from one axis", preferably by producing before/after graphs with labelled vertical axes. Additionally, it is likely that the data you import into Excel from airtable will need to be be re-organised in Excel to produce your required graph. Some indication of how the data is organised after being imported into Excel will help to define the re-organisation problem.